# Why does truffle console print function outputs to screen when they are meant for callback?

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I don't quite understand what truffle console is doing.

If I call a function with no callback, then it sends result to screen - which is probably correct.

```
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getAccounts()
[ '0x2f0bcB94F20611a2DDDB0dc6Cf7048A8AdCC6Cf5',
  '0x5C816151433f1B1117876F88944DaA9aeD395A00',
  '0x4DAF004d46482CA2a86CFd48a119c2ee8Df3a534',
  '0xEe8A3EB3F58B0C54f2107F317001Bad6a597367e',
  '0xDa9688aDe62dd636b1Fe8B94b821c435869C63cF' ]
```

However if I supply a callback, it still sends it to the screen. i.e. it sends result to screen and into my function.

```
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getAccounts( (err,res)=>{ console.log(res); })
[ '0x2f0bcB94F20611a2DDDB0dc6Cf7048A8AdCC6Cf5',
  '0x5C816151433f1B1117876F88944DaA9aeD395A00',
  '0x4DAF004d46482CA2a86CFd48a119c2ee8Df3a534',
  '0xEe8A3EB3F58B0C54f2107F317001Bad6a597367e',
  '0xDa9688aDe62dd636b1Fe8B94b821c435869C63cF' ]
[ '0x2f0bcB94F20611a2DDDB0dc6Cf7048A8AdCC6Cf5',
  '0x5C816151433f1B1117876F88944DaA9aeD395A00',
  '0x4DAF004d46482CA2a86CFd48a119c2ee8Df3a534',
  '0xEe8A3EB3F58B0C54f2107F317001Bad6a597367e',
  '0xDa9688aDe62dd636b1Fe8B94b821c435869C63cF' ]
```

Does not seem correct to me, how to turn off the screen echo, it's really annoying, especially in migration scripts, because I don't want function outputs echo'd to the screen while migration is running.

Answer (score 0):

It's a return value. Capture it by assigning to a variable and it will not go to screen.

```
var c = web3.eth.getAccounts( (err,res)=>{ console.log(res); } )
```